# Div element in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html

Can I take `div` element within the `td` element of the table? Because when I try taking it, it's not showing in the design mode of asp.net VWD?
syntax is

```
<td width="33%" id="tdselected" runat="server">
    <div id="divSelectedList" runat="server" class="divListStyle">
    </div>
    <asp:ListBox ID="lstSelected" Style="z-index: -1" runat="server" Width="200px" Height="176px"
        onmouseover="ShowDiv('SelectedList')" onmouseout="HideDiv('SelectedList')">
        <asp:ListItem>PIYUSH</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:ListBox>
</td>
```

Comment: i think what you are doing is that you used div but did not placed anything inside that you are placing the list box outside the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no its not like that you can use div it will display also in design mode
`<table class="style1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>hi hello</div></div></td>
                <td>
                    <div>hi</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>hello</div></td>
                <td>
                    <div>Bye</div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>`